# Get text from URL with PHP and REGEX

Tags: php, regex, joomla

I'm working in Joomla and need to change text on the fly based on the current URL so that I can create "area pages" for my services. I'm using a module that allows me to insert PHP so this is what i'm working with;

This is the code I copy and pasted together;

```
<?php $activeURL=basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); 
if (strpos($activeURL, 'paddington') !== false) { $area='Paddington';}
if (strpos($activeURL, 'clapham') !== false) { $area='Clapham';}
if (strpos($activeURL,'brixton') !== false) { $area='Brixton';}

echo $area . '<br/>' . "\n";

echo 'SysFix provide a wide range of computer repair services throughout '; 
echo $area; 
echo ', London and the UK. A member of our highly skilled, technical support team will visit you at home to provide assistance with you computer issues.';
echo '<br/>' . "\n";
echo '<br/>' . "\n";
echo 'As well as on site computer repairs, we also provide technical support over the internet using our remote support software which not only saves you money but is quicker too.';
```

What i'm doing is looking at the URL and if it contains a word (paddington, clapham or brixton), then set a variable to that effect with a capital letter and then echo that variable throughout my static text (article) so that it seems less like duplicate content as refers to an area.

**CAVEAT** I have around 100 areas so don't want all this code. I'm looking for a way to maybe use regex instead but sorry, i've no idea how to use it. Hoping there's an expert.

All my URLs are formed like this;

https://www.sysfix.co.uk/Computer-Repair/clapham-sw4.html

https://www.sysfix.co.uk/Computer-Repair/brixton-sw2.html

https://www.sysfix.co.uk/Computer-Repair/marylebone-w1-w1m-nw1.html

so is there a better way to do this instead of creating 100 of these;

```
if (strpos($activeURL, 'paddington') !== false) { $area='Paddington';}
```

for every area page. I guess i'm looking to extract the location name after Computer-Repair/AREANAME AND DISCARD THE REST after the next - (also making the area name a capital letter.

I can then subsequently echo $area. This i need an if set statement too in case there's a page that has a url that does not conform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
'~/Computer-Repair/\K[\w-]*?(?=-[a-z]*\d|$)~'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QtadLx/1).

**Details**

- `/Computer-Repair/` - a literal subtring
- `\K` - a match reset operator that omits the currently matched text
- `[\w-]*?` - 0+ word or `-` chars as few as possible, up to the first...
- `(?=-[a-z]*\d|$)` - `-`, then 0+ lowercase ASCII letters (`[a-z]*`) and then any digit (`\d`) or (`|`) the end of string (`$`).

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/hzgNcU):

```
$strs = ['/Computer-Repair/lancaster-gate-w2.html', '/Computer-Repair/marylebone-w1-w1m-nw1.html', '/Computer-Repair/covent-garden-wc2.html', 'https://www.sysfix.co.uk/Computer-Repair/clapham-sw4.html','https://www.sysfix.co.uk/Computer-Repair/brixton-sw2.html', 'https://www.sysfix.co.uk/Computer-Repair/marylebone-w1-w1m-nw1.html'];
foreach ($strs as $s){
    if (preg_match('~/Computer-Repair/\K[\w-]*?(?=-[a-z]*\d|$)~', $s, $m)) {
        echo preg_replace_callback('~(-)?\b(\w)~', function ($x) { 
            return (isset($x[1]) && strlen($x[1]) ? " " : "") .  ucfirst($x[2]);
        }, $m[0]) . "\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Lancaster Gate
Marylebone
Covent Garden
Clapham
Brixton
Marylebone
```

Note that `ucfirst($x[2])` will make the first letter uppercase.

Comment: Consider a more restrictive regex match, to disallow malicious code here. Perhaps `[a-zA-Z]+` instead of `[^/-]+`?

Comment: @jonasfh If any Unicode letter/digit is meant, probably `'~/Computer-Repair/\K[^\W_]+~u'` will be enough. Well, no idea what there can be in fact. We only know that the value can contain anything up to the first hyphen.

Comment: Yes Wiktor, that is definitely better that allowing any character :) I just don't consider your original answers text handling safe.

Comment: Okay so I was a little hasty as my URLs aren't all the same. Some areas have been broken down as follows;

/Computer-Repair/covent-garden-wc2.html  (REGEX shows Covent)
Computer-Repair/marylebone-w1-w1m-nw1.html (dont need the postcodes extracted - ok here)
Computer-Repair/lancaster-gate-w2.html  (Area is Lancaster Gate) REGEX shows Lancaster

Comment: I've added this until I get a reply

 if( strpos( $myarea[0], 'covent' ) !== false ) $myarea[0]='Covent Garden';